# Spark streaming window (Python) statistics

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

How can I get the standard statistics such as mean, standard deviation, median, kurtosis and skewness in spark streaming if the streams are all float values.

I need to process the statistics of stream data, hence this question. I explored the 'summary' option, however, how can I customize it or how can I extract the summary values of windowed stream.

I tried by converting it to pandas data frame but it becomes too slow.